# Image logo should maintain a size relative to the device screen size

Tags: android, user-interface, eclipse-adt

I have a basic Layout question.

When using the layout tab (rather than the coding tab) in my main.xml, I am trying to create a home screen for when my app opens.

There is going to be the logo at the top center, then 3 simple buttons below, all centered.

How do I go about formatting the Logo so it maintains a size relative to the person's screen size, and stays in the center?

I don't want to write sloppy code to where my program looks fine (UI wise) on my screen and is poorly formatted on other's screens.

Also, is there good documentation explaining all of the Property values in the layout view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different scale types for you images (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).
View attributes can be find at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html.